# ANSI codes not working in a ndarray of strings

Tags: python, numpy

I think the best way to explain my problem is to just show it:

```
import numpy as np

coloured_letters = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 2), dtype="<U100")

print("\033[1;32;40m A test \033[30m")
def fill(ndarray):
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while y < 2:
        while x < 2:
            ndarray[y][x] = "\033[1;32;40m A test \033[30m"
            x = x + 1
        x = 0
        y = y + 1


fill(coloured_letters)
print(coloured_letters)
```

Outputs:

```
 A test
[['\x1b[1;32;40m A test \x1b[30m' '\x1b[1;32;40m A test \x1b[30m']
 ['\x1b[1;32;40m A test \x1b[30m' '\x1b[1;32;40m A test \x1b[30m']]
```

Where the "A test" is in bright green with a white background.

Comment: What's the question exactly? Are you trying to print a numpy array with text containing ANSI color codes?

Comment: When you print an array containing strings it prints the representation of the strings, it doesn't interpret the strings. Try just printing the array elements themselves, rather than the whole array.

Comment: @PrestonHager that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! That fixes it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is storing exactly the values you want. However, when you print the variable `coloured_letters` numpy calls the `__repr__` or `__str__` function to convert the string into a printable representation. This means that it will translate each string into something the terminal can print with just normal ASCII characters.

If you print any element from `coloured_letters` it will print correctly. If you still want to get the array format of the numpy array you can access each element and print brackets around them as such.

```
for row in range(len(coloured_letters)):
  print("["+",".join(coloured_letters[row])+"]")
```

That will print something like the following with each `A test` being green on white.

```
[A test, A test]
[A test, A test]
```